# Django-filter ForeignKey related Model filtering

Tags: django, search, filter, model, django-filter

I've been struggling with dajngo-filter recently. I have 2 models: Book and Author.

```
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=model.CASCADE)
   length = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    year_of_birth = models.DateFiled()
```

So, I'd like to make filter page, where you can find book by it's properties (title, author etc) AND information about author. For example book shorter than 300 pages, which author is beetween 20-25 years old.

In filters.py I have:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Book, Author

class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta():
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'author']
```

And have actually no idea how to also filter by different model, which is related by ForeignKey to Book model.

I have really little experience with Dajngo, I wonder if it's very complex problem or not. :)
Thanks!

Comment: any help here please ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508935/search-input-on-every-pages-django

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically there are two important arguments for each filter:

`field_name`: The name of the model field to filter on. You can traverse “relationship paths” using Django’s `__` syntax to filter fields on a related model. ex, `author__last_name`.

`lookup_expr`: The field lookup to use when filtering. Django’s `__` syntax can again be used in order to support lookup transforms. ex, `year__gte`. For full list of field lookups you can use see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups.

Together, the field `field_name` and `lookup_expr` represent a complete Django lookup expression. A detailed explanation of lookup expressions is provided in Django’s lookup reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/lookups/#module-django.db.models.lookups.

With that in mind here is the answer:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Book, Author

class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='title', lookup_expr='iexact')
    author = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='author__last_name', lookup_expr='iexact')
    
    class Meta():
        model = Book
```

If you want to filter by exact date just add to your `BookFilter` class:

```
date_of_birth = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='author__date_of_birth', lookup_expr='exact')
```

However it would make more sense to filter by year of birth (for example to get all the books from authors born between 1980 and 1990). To do that here is what you add to `BookFilter` class:

```
birth_year__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='author__date_of_birth', lookup_expr='year__gt')
birth_year__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='author__date_of_birth', lookup_expr='year__lt')
```

Comment: Ok, but how am I supposed to filter books but author's date of birth? How to add date_of_birth to filter fields in BookFilter Meta class

Comment: Edit with answer incoming.

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot! Is it similar things with numbers not years? for example lookup_expr='number__gt' ?

Comment: Oh, it's just 'gt' :)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [the document](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html?#generating-filters-with-meta-fields) of `django-filter` package.

> Items in the fields sequence in the Meta class may include “relationship paths” using Django’s __ syntax to filter on fields on a related model.

Like so:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Book, Author

class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta():
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'author__first_name', 'author__last_name']
```

Comment: SORRY            /
         \                         /
          \    This page does     /
           ]   not exist yet.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoVenâncio, just updated it with the new url