# I am having some trouble designing API endpoint for my Django App (DRF)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am designing an API for an E-learning project. The platform enables students to take online tests. The tests contain questions and questions can have multiple options. Below is the schema for my app:

```
Test:
    id: Primary Key
    duration: Integer
    created: Timestamp

Question:
    id: Primary Key
    serial: Integer
    test: Foreign Key (Test)
    body: Char Field

Option:
    id: Primary Key
    question: Foreign Key (Question)
    body: Char Field
    correct: Boolean Field

StudentSelectedOption:
    id: Primary Key
    question: Foreign Key (Question)
    student: Foreign Key (User)
    option: Foreign Key (Option)
```

Now, the problem is that I want to create an endpoint for returning student selected options based on the requesting user

```
/test/<int:test_id>/student-answers/
```

For example if any user wants to get their answers for test id 1, they will go to /test/1/student-answers/ (The user will be extracted from the request object, because I am using token authentication)

But I am not able to filter selected options related to the test id and user. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you please add a valid url of what you want ? something like /test/2/studen-answers/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To return a filtered queryset on DRF APIVIew, you can override get_queryset method like this :**

*Assume that you have already have a `StudentSelectedOptionSerializer`*

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class StudentSelectedOptionListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer = StudentSelectedOptionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all answer of a specific test
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """

        user = self.request.user
        test_id = username = self.kwargs['test_id']
        queryset = StudentSelectedOption.objects.filter(question__test_id=test_id, student_id=user.id)
        return queryset
```

**Note :** You can traverse “relationship paths” using Django’s __ syntax to filter fields on a related model. EX: `question__test_id` in your case.
More info on [DRF filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/). And [Django filter trough foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989320/django-filter-foreignkey-related-model-filtering)